# How to compare single paths of a decision tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

I want to compare single paths of a decision tree in one function in javascript.

I only know how to do this, as the nodes are adding up but thats just comparing the nodes.
Instead I want to look at one path and then look at the next one.

for example: next decision should be in `range` of -3. given are the numbers `[9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 0]`. The sum of the list is the `value`. The path with a `length` of 6 with the `biggest value` is wanted.

```
                      2 - 0
                  3 <
               5<     0 
             /    2 - 0
           6 
          /  \    2 - 0
               3<
                  0
     8         2 - 0
       \    3<
   /    5 <    0
            2 - 0

9               2 - 0
            3 <
         5<     0 
   \   /    2 - 0
     6 
       \   2 - 0
        3<
           0
```

I want to compare those `paths`:

```
[9,6,3,0],
[9,6,3,2,0],
[9,6,5,2,0],
[9,6,5,3,0],
[9,6,5,3,2,0],
[9,8,6,3,0],
[9,8,6,3,2,0],
[9,8,6,5,2,0],
[9,8,6,5,3,0],
[9,8,6,5,3,2,0],
```

and instead of calculating every `path` and then comparing them simultaneously, I want to only calculate the first `path` and then compare it with the second `path` like this:

```
[9,6,3,0], //value 18
[9,6,3,2,0]//value 21

   || which one has the nearest length of 6 with the most Value?
   \/
[9,6,3,2,0]//value 21

[9,6,3,2,0],//value 21
[9,6,5,2,0] //value 23

   || which one has the nearest length of 6 with the most Value?
   \/ 
[9,6,5,2,0] //value 23

... and so on
```

how to compare only 2 paths at a time instead of every ?

*Edit 1 :*

**My Code so far:**  https://replit.com/@RubyKanima/BestSumwithlength#index.js

```
const numbers = [9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 0];
const starting_node = Math.max(...numbers) + 3;

const path = (current_node, memo ={}) => {
  if (current_node in memo) return memo[current_node];
  if (current_node == 0) return [[]];
  let paths = [];
  let tmp_nodes = [];
  for (n of numbers) {
    if (n >= current_node - 3 && n < current_node) {
      tmp_nodes.push(n);
    }
  }
  for (let tmp of tmp_nodes) {
    const tmp_path = path(tmp);
    const tmp_paths = tmp_path.map(way => [tmp, ...way]);
    paths.push(...tmp_paths);
  }
  memo[current_node] = paths; 
  paths = paths.filter(x => x.length <= 6);
  return paths;
};

const bestPath = all_paths => {
  all_paths = all_paths.filter(x => (x.length = 6));
  let bestValue = 0;
  let bestPath = null;
  for (let path of all_paths) {
    let value = 0;
    for (node of path) value += node;
    if (value > bestValue) {
      bestValue = value;
      bestPath = path;
    }
  }
  return bestPath;
};
const path_array = path(starting_node);
console.log(bestPath(path_array));
```

It does the job, but if I get over a thousand numbers it gets a stack overflow. (In the example I reduced some numbers to make it easier to understand, in reality the range is -360 and not -3)

***Biggest Problem***: too much data

***How to solve it?***: Comparing only 2 Paths at a time and then calculating the next Path.

***What I want to know***: How to only calculate 2 Paths.

Comment: what did you do so far? add some code how you are currently compare them

Comment: @J_K I edited my Question and also edited my Code. It does what it should do but it doesnt do it efficiently. I also have a code with memoization but there it also gets a stack overflow due to 1500 nodes given, where it's paths are huge. One of the problem being the calculating of all routes and not only those which have a length smaller or equal to 6. But the biggest issue is still: calculating all paths instead of 2 at a time.

Comment: I added an answer using merge sort algorithm. see if that helps you @rubykanima

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote a merge sort algorithm and I added some performance time calculation for both your solution and the merge sort solution. In this scenario, it seems the merge sort performs better. It compares two arrays at the time, until it reaches the one you need. Try this on your data, which should be bigger and see if it works better.

```js
const numbers = [9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 0];
const starting_node = Math.max(...numbers) + 3;

const path = (current_node, memo ={}) => {
  if (current_node in memo) return memo[current_node];
  if (current_node == 0) return [[]];
  let paths = [];
  let tmp_nodes = [];
  for (n of numbers) {
    if (n >= current_node - 3 && n < current_node) {
      tmp_nodes.push(n);
    }
  }
  for (let tmp of tmp_nodes) {
    const tmp_path = path(tmp);
    const tmp_paths = tmp_path.map(way => [tmp, ...way]);
    paths.push(...tmp_paths);
  }
  memo[current_node] = paths; 
  paths = paths.filter(x => x.length <= 6);
  return paths;
};

const bestPath = all_paths => {
  all_paths = all_paths.filter(x => (x.length = 6));
  let bestValue = 0;
  let bestPath = null;
  for (let path of all_paths) {
    let value = 0;
    for (node of path) value += node;
    if (value > bestValue) {
      bestValue = value;
      bestPath = path;
    }
  }
  return bestPath;
};
//-----merge sort algorithm---------
const sumArr = arr => arr.reduce((acc, next)=> acc+next)
function merge(arr1, arr2){
    if (sumArr(arr1) > sumArr(arr2)) {
        return arr1
    } else if(sumArr(arr1) < sumArr(arr2)) {
        return arr2
    } else {return arr1}
}
function mergeSort(arr){
    if(arr.length <= 1) return arr[0];
    let mid = Math.floor(arr.length/2);
    let left = mergeSort(arr.slice(0,mid));
    let right = mergeSort(arr.slice(mid));
    return merge(left, right);
}
//-----end of merge sort algorithm------

const path_array = path(starting_node);
const start = performance.now()
console.log(bestPath(path_array));
const end = performance.now()
console.log("bestPath performance ", end-start)
const start2 = performance.now()
console.log(mergeSort(path_array))
const end2 = performance.now()
console.log("mergeSort performance ", end2-start2)
```

Comment: for me it just says: 

ReferenceError: performance is not defined
    at /home/runner/match/index.js:60:15

Comment: I just looked a little bit closer and I see some flaws. For example: in line 41 to 43 are the variables "result","i" and "j", which are never used. Also i can tell by looking at it, it would not make a difference because you still take the variables from path_array -> the problem is in path() because it calculates all paths in one go. 
The problem is more the code itself than the lack of code. But still I came up with an idea, which I will try later. Still thank you and I will try to use some of your code if possible ;D

Comment: yeah. I took the code from a codebase of mine and adjusted it very fast. those variables are not used and can be removed. the part of code I added is to replace the best_Path() function you had which had a low performance. That was the part comparing the paths.